# For static domain files, cookies are still attached. How to solve? ASP.NET , IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019, static-content

My application is ASP.NET 4.5 Website : https://www.monstermmorpg.com/

I serve all the static content from a static domain https://static.monstermmorpg.com

However cookies are still getting attached such as

```
    cookie: _ga=GA1.2.xxx; 
_gid=GA1.2.xxxx; 
_gat_gtag_UA_xx_4=1; 
__qca=P0-xxx; __gads=ID=a4xxx:T=1xxx3:RT=16xxx3:S=x
```

This is the web config of the static IIS folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

OS : Windows server 2019

Comment: Can you please provide some more information ? From developer tool how is your cookie look like ?  I am assuming that you have hosted two as different site in IIS.

Comment: this cookies are from google ads and statistics - not from asp.net

Comment: I also check your site, no cookies exist on `static.` so you probably see some from your tests or you have from before. Delete them all and check again.

Comment: @Aristos you may be right. after i did check from private window edge, i dont see cookies attached to image

Answer (score 1):

Many times as we develop a site we have left cookies on our browsers that no longer used from our program - but they are still there from previous sessions.

Your cookies looks and are from google ads and statistics - so its not from IIS, not from you.

I suggest to clear the cookies from your site and test again, or how you do it with the use of a private session, or with some other browser.

I check your site and see no cookies on the `static.` url.